# comment button shows only logged in users wordpress

Tags: comments

I have a question in my blog site https://www.jesuisblocus.org . the comment button shows Registered users only.
[image]

Logged in users shows the comment button.

Other users shows only part of the button. 
Anyone have any idea why this thing happens? All the wordpress comments settings are fine. Is this a wordpress issue or theme issue? I used Betheme in this blog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's css issue. add this css your current theme style.css

```
p.form-submit {

    clear: both;

}
```

Comment: If is useful then accept the answer

Comment: Thanks  for your reply. But this is not work.